# Pluggable service assemblies. How to add list of assemblies without hardcoding tem in the AppHost constructor

Tags: servicestack

I have question about how to make service assemblies pluggable (read them from config file) into the ServiceStack.
I want to register my services assemblies from configuration file and not to hard code them in the `AppHost` constructor like this:

```cs
public appHost() : base("My Pluggable Web Services", typeof(ServiceAssembly1).Assembly,  typeof(AnotherServiceAssembly).Assembly) { }
```

I couldn't find other way to register the assemblies outside of this constructor. The constructor also accepts params and does not have overload for example with `IEnumerable<Assembly>` as parameter.
The idea is to be able to plug service assemblies without touching the service stack REST web site.

I looked at the `Plugin` interface but I think it is more suitable to be used to extend the service stack not to dynamically plug service assemblies.

Are there any way to implement such pluggable service assemblies feature with the current service stack release? Can you also add constructor overload that will accept the array of assembly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of your ServiceStack's `AppHost` is to be a bespoke class customized for your solution that has hard references to all your service dependencies. It's much easier to verify your application is configured correctly, at build time if you declare your dependencies in code as opposed to un-typed configuration.

Having said that you can override the strategy that ServiceStack uses to discover your Service types by overriding [AppHostBase.CreateServiceManager()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/AppHostBase.cs#L34):

```
protected virtual ServiceManager CreateServiceManager(params Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
{       
    return new ServiceManager(assembliesWithServices);
    //Alternative way to inject Container + Service Resolver strategy
    //return new ServiceManager(new Container(),
    //    new ServiceController(() => assembliesWithServices.ToList().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())));
}
```

Otherwise you can still do what you want by just passing your assemblies into your AppHost, e.g:

```
var appHost = new AppHost("Service Name", MyConfig.LoadAssembliesFromConfig());
(new AppHost()).Init();
```